# Add typos in resharper

Tags: resharper

While using Resharper, and it's ReSpeller, I am trying to remove certain words from the dictionary.
For example (though not the most relevant), I want to see a typo warning (or something of that sort) whenever a curse word is added in code (comment, method name, etc).
Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, only adding words to the dictionary is possible, but not removing them. Maybe you can tweak something with a dedicated plugin, but with the default software, there is IMHO no way.